# SQL Server 2008 - User-defined function returning concatenate entries and "multi-part identifier could not be bound" error

Tags: sql-server, ssms, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a specific function to return a three random entries from three separate columns (these could be from three separate tables in the future but currently they are all from the same source table).

My user defined function is as below, when tested in T-SQL specifying the variables this works perfectly. When a function is created to do the exact same thing this creates the error

> multi-part identifier could not be bound

Code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create function dbo.Example
    (@field1 varchar(50), @field2 varchar(50), @field3 varchar(50))
returns varchar(100)
as
begin
    Select @field1 = Fieldexample1 
    from DatabaseExample1 
    Order by (select newid from Newidworkaroundview)

    Select @field2 = Fieldexample2 
    from DatabaseExample2 
    Order by (select newid from Newidworkaroundview)

    Select @field3 = Fieldexample3 
    from DatabaseExample3 
    Order by (select newid from Newidworkaroundview)

    Return (Select top 1 @field1)+' '+(Select top 1 @field2)+' '+(select top 1 @field3)
end
```

The `newid` column from Newidworkaroundview is simply a workaround I used in order to order the column by `newid()` without being able to use `newid()` function.

I think the issue stems from how I am returning the results, but I cannot think of why this would work in T-SQL that being the case.

If anyone has experienced this before or could give me some tips I would be really grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Your function is defined to return VARCHAR so modify your RETURN statement to

```
Return @field1+' '+@field2+' '+@field3
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to set multiple values in field variables.   Use in this way.

```
set @field1 = (select top 1 Fieldexample1 
from DatabaseExample1 
Order by (select newid from Newidworkaroundview))

set @field2 = (select top 1 Fieldexample2 
from DatabaseExample2 
Order by (select newid from Newidworkaroundview))

set @field3 = (select top 1 Fieldexample3 
from DatabaseExample3 
Order by (select newid from Newidworkaroundview))

return @field1 + ' ' + @field2 + ' ' + @field3
```

Comment: Thank you for your help however, after making your suggested changes I am still receiving an error of multipart identifier could not be bound.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql varchar(50)
    set @field1 = select top 1 stFieldexample1 
    from DatabaseExample1 
    Order by (select newid from Newidworkaroundview)

    sett @field2 = select top 1 Fieldexample2 
    from DatabaseExample2 
    Order by (select newid from Newidworkaroundview)

    set @field3 = select top 1 Fieldexample3 
    from DatabaseExample3 
    Order by (select newid from Newidworkaroundview)
    set @sql=(select concat(@field1,' ',@field2,' ',@field3))

    Return @sql
end
```

use

```
 select   [dbo].[Example] ('x',' y',' z') fieldx
```

[image]